# What is the best way to check if list contain any element of specific collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

What is the best way to get a list which only contains some data?

My application is on ASP.NET CORE 5 Web API. It has `KitchenOrigin`s which each contain a collection of `Recipes`.

```
   public class KitchenOrigin
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Code { get; set; }
            public ICollection<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

While my application is running, I'm seeding some data (`Recipes`).

**`KitchenOrigin`s are very many, so I would like to get only list of `KitchenOrigin`s that contains `Recipe`s.**

Like in title: What is the best way of doing that?
Maybe `IQueryable`? Could you help me with that?

Here is my code:

#### Repo

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<KitchenOrigin>> GetKitchenOriginsWithRecipesAsync()
        {
            return await _context.KitchenOrigins
            .Include(k => k.Recipes)
           .ToListAsync();
        }
```

#### Controller

```
[HttpGet("kitchen-origins")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetKitchenOrigins()
        {
            var kitchenOrigins = await _recipeRepository.GetKitchenOriginsWithRecipesAsync();
            return Ok(kitchenOrigins);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.Where()` to filter and `.Any()` to check whether it's empty or not.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<KitchenOrigin>> GetKitchenOriginsWithRecipesAsync()
{
    return await _context.KitchenOrigins
      .Where(k => k.Recipes.Any())
      .Include(k => k.Recipes)
      .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: beat me to it, but can you put the predicate and the conditions in the any statement for the op please

Comment: @SimonPrice I believe he just wanted kitchenOrigins that has recipes didn't specify any filteration/predicate for the recipes. unless i am missing something